# Button Target in Java

Tags: java, swing, button, jpanel, target

i try to make an application with java (GUI), so i'm using WINDOWBUILDER and Eclipse as IDE.

So I'm asking about how to set the target of buttons I'm using,, so for example, if a user click on a button, the content of this button should be called in main Frame (centre of the window - see picture) and if the user clicks on another button, its appropriate content should be called in the same place of the window. i don't want to use many `JPanel` for the target, I prefer a nice and clean way to do it, one `JFrame` maybe for all buttons? And what about the classes? Should i make a Separate class for each Button event? and then just call the class?

[image]

Comment: You mean action listeners dedicated to components?

Comment: What do you mean by "content of this button" and how should the content be called?

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: yes action or events associated to buttons, with content i meant what should appear when we click on a button,, i already saw the tutorial in the page of oracle, doesn't really help,, i knw already how to add action to buttons, but jow to guide it? how could we set the right place to be the target place,, the picture is quite simple and should explain what i need

Comment: Please provide the link to the Oracle tutorial you are referring to. Are you trying to just make the content of the "target" area change dependent on what button is pressed? Meaning if the top button is pressed you display an apple and if the next button is pressed the apple disappears and displays an orange?